# .NET library for pluralisation

Tags: .net, pluralize

What's the best library (if one exists) for converting nouns to and from plurals?

Comment: You might want to indicate what languages you need to support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a port of Rails' Inflector class at http://andrewpeters.net/inflectornet/

Comment: Andrew Peters is on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/users/608/andrew-peters

Answer (score 0):

I created an extensible inflector for .Net. It now supports english and portuguese, but you can add other languages by creating a RuleSet. It's available under GPL at

https://github.com/svallory/Flexer